# Jest manual mocks with create-react-app: How to use mock values in test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, create-react-app

I have a React project set up with create-react-app. In the project there is a `Configuration` class that holds environment specific values. It looks like this (minimized version for illustration):

```
# src/Configuration.js
class Configuration {
  getBackendUrl() { return "https://somewhere.com/" }
}
export default new Configuration();
```

As this configuration class is used widely among the components, there is a manual mock setting the proper values for testing:

```
# src/__mocks__/Configuration.js
class Configuration {
  getBackendUrl = jest.fn(() => {return "http://localhost:3001" });
}
export default new Configuration();
```

The mock is loaded globally in `setupTests.js`:

```
# src/setupTests.js
jest.mock('./Configuration');
```

All tests, where the `Configuration` class is used implicitly, work correct and use the mock values.

But now I have a test where I want to assert with the actual mock values of the `Configuration` class. The following test code is stripped down to the core essence, in reality I'm using `nock` to mock the API server and then test correct handling in redux.

```
# src/somemodule/demo.test.js
import Configuration from '../Configuration';

describe('somemodule/demo', () => {
  it('uses correct configuration values', () => {
    expect(Configuration.getBackendUrl()).toEqual("http://localhost:3001")
  });
});
```

The problem is that `Configuration.getBackendUrl()` is always `undefined`. Can I somehow achieve that the mock value is returned?

I could fix it by manually overwriting the mock in the `beforeEach` test suite method like this, but I'd prefer to avoid duplication: `Configuration.getBackendUrl.mockImplementation(() => 'http://localhost:3001')`.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: added the actual used code of the mock.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for initially asking the question with not reflecting the real used code.

In fact the mock of `Configuration` used the following code (the question is now adjusted with it):

```
# src/__mocks__/Configuration.js
class Configuration {
  getBackendUrl = jest.fn(() => {return "http://localhost:3001" });
}
export default new Configuration();
```

This will always return a `MockInstance` per method and thus the undefined in the test.
If the mock is fixed to not use the `jest.fn` calls, then it works:

```
# src/__mocks__/Configuration.js
class Configuration {
  getBackendUrl(){ return "http://localhost:3001" };
}
export default new Configuration();
```

Once again sorry and maybe it is helpful for someone.